# Norms on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

So with respect to the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ induced by the standard absolute value, the real numbers can be constructed as a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. With respect to the metric $d_p(x,y)=|x-y|_p$ induced by the [p-adic norm](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aP-adic_Norm), the p-adic numbers can be constructed as a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Are there any other norms that induce metrics which lead to different completions of $\mathbb{Q}$? I remember reading that the answer was "no" somewhere, but I can't find where and I can't justify it myself.

Comment: [Ostrowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem).

Comment: The trivial absolute value has completion ${\mathbf Q}$ itself. Other than that, see the previous comment.